# Use d3 stratify to transform flat data to hierarchy data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3 to create my first treemap.
This is my dataset:

```js
const dataset = [
  { color: "red", isActive: false },
  { color: "red", isActive: true },
  { color: "red", isActive: true },
  { color: "red", isActive: true },
  { color: "blue", isActive: false },
  { color: "blue", isActive: false },
  { color: "blue", isActive: true },
  { color: "green", isActive: false },
  { color: "green", isActive: false },
  { color: "green", isActive: true },
  { color: "green", isActive: true },
  { color: "green", isActive: true },
];
```

So I can summarise info in this way:

```
red
  isActive = true -> #3
  isActive = false -> #1
blue
  isActive = true -> #1
  isActive = false -> #2
green
  isActive = true -> #2
  isActive = false -> #3
```

because there are 3 red element that are active and only one that is not active, etc.

I would like to build a treemap like this:

[image]

There are 3 rectangles, one for each color and each of this is split on two: the yellow rectangle indicates the active area, the white one the not actve area.

I think that to use `d3.treemap` I need to transform my data to obtain a hierarchy format, to do so I read I can use  `d3.stratify` but how?

Comment: What version of D3 are you using?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie the last one

Answer (score 2):

Your data isn't in the right shape to use with [`d3.stratify`](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#stratify) because each 'row' represents multiple levels of a hierarchy where `d3.stratify` is expecting each row to describe a single parent-child relationship. Also, for the treemap to assign different shaped rectangles you need a value to work with so you need something to aggregate (i.e. a number, not a true/ false).

However, you can flip `dataset` into another array that you can pass to `d3.stratify` and from there into [`d3.treemap`](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#treemap) - the steps for this particular data are:

- create a `root` with null parent and null value
- for each `color` add a child with this `root` as parent, and null value
- for each active count (i.e. `isActive: true`) add a child to the `color`
- for each inactive count (i.e. `isActive: false`) add a child to the `color`

See below:

```js
// your initial data set
const dataset = [
  { color: "red", isActive: false },
  { color: "red", isActive: true },
  { color: "red", isActive: true },
  { color: "red", isActive: true },
  { color: "blue", isActive: false },
  { color: "blue", isActive: false },
  { color: "blue", isActive: true },
  { color: "green", isActive: false },
  { color: "green", isActive: false },
  { color: "green", isActive: true },
  { color: "green", isActive: true },
  { color: "green", isActive: true },
];

// to use stratify need array items of {name: foo, parent: bar, value: baz}
// create root
const dataForStratify = [{name: "root", parent: null, value: null}];

// add I children for unique colors
const colors = [...new Set(dataset.map(k => k.color))];
colors.forEach(k => dataForStratify.push({name: k, parent: "root", value: null}));

// add active inactive children for each color 
const colorCounts = colors.reduce((a, c) => {
  const colorItems = dataset.filter(k => k.color === c); 
  const actives = colorItems.filter(k => k.isActive === true).length;
  const inactives = colorItems.filter(k => k.isActive === false).length;
  a.push({
    name: "active",
    parent: c,
    value: actives
  });
  a.push({
    name: "inactive",
    parent: c,
    value: inactives
  });
  return a;
}, []);
colorCounts.forEach(k => dataForStratify.push(k));

console.log(dataForStratify);
```

Which will return this (as `dataForStratify`):

```
[
  // root
  {"name": "root", "parent": null, "value": null},
  // color children
  {"name": "red", "parent": "root", "value": null},
  {"name": "blue", "parent": "root", "value": null},
  {"name": "green", "parent": "root", "value": null},
  // active/ inactive children of colors
  {"name": "active", "parent": "red", "value": 3},
  {"name": "inactive", "parent": "red", "value": 1},
  {"name": "active", "parent": "blue", "value": 1},
  {"name": "inactive", "parent": "blue", "value": 2},
  {"name": "active","parent": "green", "value": 3},
  {"name": "inactive", "parent": "green", "value": 2}
]
```

You can then create a standard `d3.stratify` function:

```
const stratify = d3.stratify()
  .parentId(d => d.parent)
  .id(d => d.name)
```

And pass this to the `d3.treemap`:

```
const root = d3.treemap()
  .tile(d3.treemapSquarify)
  .size([width, height])
  .padding(padding)
  (stratify(dataForStratify)
    .sum(d => d.value)
    .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value));
```

Full working example:

```js
// your initial data set
const dataset = [
  { color: "red", isActive: false },
  { color: "red", isActive: true },
  { color: "red", isActive: true },
  { color: "red", isActive: true },
  { color: "blue", isActive: false },
  { color: "blue", isActive: false },
  { color: "blue", isActive: true },
  { color: "green", isActive: false },
  { color: "green", isActive: false },
  { color: "green", isActive: true },
  { color: "green", isActive: true },
  { color: "green", isActive: true },
];

// to use stratify need array items of {name: foo, parent: bar, value: baz}
// create root
const dataForStratify = [{name: "root", parent: null, value: null}];

// add I children for unique colors
const colors = [...new Set(dataset.map(k => k.color))];
colors.forEach(k => dataForStratify.push({name: k, parent: "root", value: null}));

// add active inactive children for each color 
const colorCounts = colors.reduce((a, c) => {
  const colorItems = dataset.filter(k => k.color === c); 
  const actives = colorItems.filter(k => k.isActive === true).length;
  const inactives = colorItems.filter(k => k.isActive === false).length;
  a.push({
    name: "active",
    parent: c,
    value: actives
  });
  a.push({
    name: "inactive",
    parent: c,
    value: inactives
  });
  return a;
}, []);
colorCounts.forEach(k => dataForStratify.push(k));

// stratify function
const stratify = d3.stratify()
  .parentId(d => d.parent)
  .id(d => d.name)

// basic viz
const width = 260;
const height = 180;
const padding = 4;

const color = d => {
  if (!d.parent) return "#fff";
  if (d.children) return d.data.name;
  return (d.data.name === "active") ? "#cc0" : "#fff";
}

// pass stratified dataset into the treemap function
const root = d3.treemap()
  .tile(d3.treemapSquarify)
  .size([width, height])
  .padding(padding)
  (stratify(dataForStratify)
    .sum(d => d.value)
    .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value));

const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

const node = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(d3.group(root, d => d.height))
  .join("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(d => d[1])
  .join("g")
  .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x0},${d.y0})`);

node.append("rect")
  .attr("fill", d => color(d))
  .attr("width", d => d.x1 - d.x0)
  .attr("height", d => d.y1 - d.y0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```